# Netbeans 7.4beta complains about JSF </ui:repeat> in <script>

Tags: javascript, jsf, netbeans, xhtml

I have an XHTML file with backing EJBs and an javascript  tag, which contains a JSF  tag. As follows:

```
<script>
    ...
    <ui:repeat value="#{sections.listControlsNames}" var="listName">
        { id: '#{listName}', name:'#{listName}', parent: 'controls'},
    </ui:repeat> <-- Netbeans has a problem here
    ...
</script>
```

In fact, there's more than just this one repeat tag and they all irritate Netbeans in the same as long as they are in a script tag.

What Netbeans says is

```
Expected an operand but found <
  </ui:repeat>
  ^
```

I've been using the version of Netbeans in the Ubuntu repo before this and it didn't has a problem. Any ideas on how to make it either stop complaining or to satisfy it anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fixed in latest Dev builds (after 7.4 Beta), you can download it from [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/netbeans/trunk/nightly/latest)